# React Native - Update AsyncStorage item nested key value?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have a user stored via `AsyncStorage` like this:

```
// data has a few key/value pairs for the user object
AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data));
```

One of the key/value pairs in `data` is `question_count` with a value of `10`

When the user deletes a question, how can I decrement the `question_count` value by 1 in `AsyncStorage` so the value is `9`?

Here is what I tried:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(data => {
    data.question_count--;
});
```

But that doesn't change the value. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should save the value again after decrementing it.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem( 'user' )
    .then( data => {

      // the string value read from AsyncStorage has been assigned to data
      console.log( data );

      // transform it back to an object
      data = JSON.parse( data );
      console.log( data );

      // Decrement
      data.question_count--;
      console.log( data );

      //save the value to AsyncStorage again
      AsyncStorage.setItem( 'user', JSON.stringify( data ) );

    }).done();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: what about if there is a huge data, on that time I think this might take more time